# What was the Bradbury short story featuring birds whose songs were like musical compositions?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, animals, music, ray-bradbury

I may be mixing some things up here, but to my memory there is a short story in one of the collections by Ray Bradbury in which the protagonist is involved with transcribing birdsong so complex it could be compared to intentionally-composed music. Does this ring any bells for anyone? Thank you!

Comment: Reallife:  The [Lyrebird](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyrebird#Vocalizations_and_mimicry). Also, [two](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VjE0Kdfos4Y) [videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bc-l-KfxvCw) of its range.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now fairly certain this is [“Once More, Legato”](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?64184), published in 1995:

> Fentriss sat up in his chair in the garden in the middle of a fine autumn and listened. The drink in his hand remained unsipped, his friend Black unspoken to, the fine house unnoticed, the very weather itself neglected, for there was a veritable fountain of sound in the air above them.
>
> "My God," he said. "Do you hear?"
>
> "What, the birds?" asked his friend Black, doing just the opposite, sipping his drink, noticing the weather, admiring the rich house, and neglecting the birds entirely until this moment.